# Java 8 Streams - How to get an equivalent of partitioningBy() with Integer keys?

Tags: java, list, hashmap, java-stream, predicate

In the code shown below, `p` is a predicate of type `Predicate<String>`.

```
Map<Boolean, List<String>> partitioned = numbers.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(p));
```

Is it possible to convert the `boolean` keys to the `int` type inside the partitioning logic rather than having another stream?

Looks like it could be done with `grouping`.

```
Map<String, List<String>> targetTableColumnListMap = nqColumnMapList.stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        e -> e.getKey().toUpperCase(), 
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())
    ));
```

Comment: Well, I suppose you could transform the result of  your partitioning Collector by composing it with a finisher function using [collectingAndThen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the terminal operation `collect(Collectors.toMap())` to group by your predicate and instead of returning its `boolean` value as the key you could use a ternary operator to return either 1 or 0.

> to convert the boolean keys to the int type

Then, you could map to that key a `List` built on the `String` you tested the `Predicate` with, and to handle the colliding cases you could add the `List` associated to the second key into the `List` corresponding to the first key.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
//My silly test Predicate
Predicate<String> p = s -> s.length() > 4;

//Mapping the numbers list
Map<Integer, List<String>> partitioned = numbers.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> p.test(s) ? 1 : 0, 
            s -> new ArrayList<>(List.of(s)), 
            (list1, list2) -> {
                list1.addAll(list2);
                return list1;
            }
        ));
```

Here, there's also a link to test the code:

https://ideone.com/Kd8xrI

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to convert the boolean keys to the `int` type inside the
> partitioning logic

So you need to associate the values in a list with `0` and `1` (*for instance, in order to store the data into the database*) based on the given *predicate*.

For that, instead of `partitioningBy()` you can use collector [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)) in conjunction with the *predicate*.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> partitioned = numbers.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(num -> predicate.test(num) ? 1 : 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that below class -

```
public class Employee {
    int id;
    String name;
    int age;
    String gender;
// getters n setters
}
```

// Now to group or get the count of, Employees based on Gender, we can use below codes

```
Map<String, Long> noOfMaleAndFemaleEmployees =
        employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getGender, Collectors.counting()));
                
System.out.println(noOfMaleAndFemaleEmployees);

System.out.println(employeeList.stream().map(Employee::getGender)
                .filter(e -> e.equalsIgnoreCase("male")).count());
```

// Filters can be used as well

```
System.out.println(employeeList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(e-> e.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase("Male"), 
                        Collectors.counting())));
```

Comment: why should `gender` be a String and not an enum? Why do you leave code in the text of the answer `// ...`? What new does this answer bring about? It's the same use of `grouping` as in the accepted answer in my opinion